# SQL Server : what does FLO.Tablename mean?

Tags: sql

I tried googling it but without result.

For some time I have been working on a old project someone else started many years ago.

Today while working on it I came across this data access class with some weird query.

```
SELECT 
    FLO.LEFTOVER_DATE, FLO.LEFTOVER_ID, ANIM.ANIMAL_NUMBER
FROM 
    FEED_LEFTOVERS AS FLO, ANIMALS AS ANIM
WHERE 
    FLO.ANIMAL_ID = ANIM.ANIMAL_ID
```

The thing I don't understand on this line is what the `FLO.` means.

I first thought it was just part of the table name but it clearly isn't (I did check). Googling didn't point me to any information about it either.

Thus I was wondering if anyone here would be able to give me an explanation about it?

Comment: `FLO`is an alias for `FEED_LEFTOVERS`. See here: `FEED_LEFTOVERS AS FLO` And it's not "Weird", it's perfectly normal and widely used :)

Comment: @Pikoh Thank you, i clearly missed that. Thanks for explaining makes a ot of sense now.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s So i would be better of rewriting that part to make it more up to date?

Comment: @BlackLotus: ***yes!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) name given to table in sql query.

eg:

Alias name for table `FEED_LEFTOVERS` is `FLO`. Similarly `ANIM` for `ANIMALS`

Comment: Thank u very much. I clearly overlooked that. Will mark this as answer once the 10 minutes are over!

Answer (score 0):

The below queries were both similar. The first one is with **Table Alias** and the second one without.

```
SELECT 
    FLO.LEFTOVER_DATE, FLO.LEFTOVER_ID, ANIM.ANIMAL_NUMBER
FROM 
    FEED_LEFTOVERS AS FLO, ANIMALS AS ANIM
WHERE 
    FLO.ANIMAL_ID = ANIM.ANIMAL_ID

--Is similar as the below Query.

SELECT 
    FEED_LEFTOVERS.LEFTOVER_DATE, FEED_LEFTOVERS.LEFTOVER_ID, ANIMALS.ANIMAL_NUMBER
FROM 
    FEED_LEFTOVERS , ANIMALS 
WHERE 
    FEED_LEFTOVERS.ANIMAL_ID = ANIMALS.ANIMAL_ID
```